# MySQL SELECT 1 vs SELECT `field_id` AND COUNT 1 vs COUNT (*) or COUNT (`field_id`) Performance wise

Tags: mysql, count

I have a very simple question.
I want to know if a certain database row exists.

I generally use :

```
SELECT 1 FROM `my_table` WHERE `field_x` = 'something'
```

Then I fetch the result with :

```
$row = self::$QueryObject->fetch();
```

And check if any results :

```
if(isset($row[1]) === true){
    return(true);
}
```

You can do this also with :

```
COUNT 1 FROM `my_table` WHERE `field_x` = 'something'
```

And similar to `COUNT * FROM`my_table`and`COUNT `field_id` FROM `my_table

But I was wondering.. How does this relate to performance?

Are there any cons to using `SELECT 1` or `COUNT 1`??
My feeling says that select INTEGER 1 means the lowest load.

But is this actually true??

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually all your solutions are suboptimal :) What you do with your queries is reading every row there is to be found, even if you add `limit`. Do it like this:

```
SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM `my_table` WHERE `field_x` = 'something');
```

`EXISTS` returns 1 if something was found, 0 if not. It stops searching as soon as an entry was found. What you select in the subquery doesn't matter, you can even select `null`.

Also keep in mind, that `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)` are very different from `COUNT(column_name)`. `COUNT(*)` counts every row, while `COUNT(column_name)` only count the rows that are not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the LIMIT 1 to the end of the query then SELECT works better than COUNT especially when you have a large table.

Comment: Still suboptimal :) feel free to have a look at my answer.